# Cloud firestore rules using exist() does it count as a read?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am storing a collection of documents of blocked users.
I am checking if the request is from a blocked user or not by checking if the email exist within the blocked collection

```
allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/blocked/$(request.auth.token.email)) == false;
```

does checking if the document exist count as a read?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `exists()` counts as a read toward your billing.  They also count against the [max number of reads you can perform per request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#security_rule_limits).

Comment: What if i use get() but the document does not exist. Does that count as a read too?

Comment: Yes, all queries cost at least one read.  You're paying for the cost of consulting an index for the collection, which could be huge.

Comment: That means checking for blocked users will cost an extra read everytime it hits the rule. Which is gona rekt up the reads. Whats the best way to store blocked users and ensure they dont have access? Because if i am checking if the person is blocked for every read, thats going to double the reads.

Comment: There is no alternative if you want something dynamic.  You will have to pay for the reads.

Comment: Hmmn i was thinking by using custom claims. That wont count as reads right?

Comment: Exactly, custom claims don't count as a read. Although it has limitations, if used well it can scale perfectly.