# Does Firestore security rules return early?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have 2 conditions for checking permission to the user. The first condition doesn't require any database query but the second one does.
For Example

```
allow read, write: if (docId == request.auth.uid);
allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(docId)).data[request.auth.uid].membership == true
```

My database is structured in a way that I need to give read and write access if `docId` belongs to that user. Otherwise, the user might be accessing something from a group which he's part of. In which case I'll make a DB query and check if the user really a member.

Suppose a user is accessing a document that belongs only to him, in which case the DB query is not required and the first condition should return `true`.

Will the rule still make a DB query?

Comment: "Also, does exists check increase any DB read count?" Yes it does (see a.o. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55257311). I'd remove this last question from your post to prevent it being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I was confused since `exists` must be checking only if a document with that id exists, rather than reading it's content.

Comment: Checking for existence requires the use of a massively scalable index, which is definitely not a "free" operation from the perspective of Firestore internals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you have two conditions:

```
allow read: if X;
allow read: if Y;
```

This is the same as a logical OR between X and Y in the order they were defined:

```
allow read: if X || Y;
```

The security rules language will short circuit when X evaluates `true`, and skip the evaluation of Y.

So, if your first condition `(docId == request.auth.uid)` evaluates `true`, then there is no need to get the document in the second condition.